# It is both Truth and Lie!

Tags: riddle

> It is both Truth and Lie,
>   Depends on the Point of View,
>   Depends on the Person,
>   It is encountered in Religion,
>   With It a Person can even kill
>   Without a second thought!

What is "It"?

Comment: It is the word of god.

Comment: No sorry! I´ll give some Tips with the flow of the time.

Comment: Are the first two lines of the question text significant?  If not, I'd suggest you edit them out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the answer:

> Beliefs

It is both Truth and Lie, Depends on the Point of View,
Depends on the Person

> Some people don't believe in a religion, hence atheists.

It is encountered in Religion

> Religion is a set of beliefs.

With It a Person can even kill Without a second thought!

> There are some people who use beliefs for doing terrible things.

Comment: I thought people would need a little more time to get it. Well done. Next time I´ll try to do a more difficult one! :)

Comment: This is the first time I actually solved a riddle lol.